# I am interested to change my OS from android to your OS

Tags: 12.04, wireless, sound, android, smartphone

im using Alcatel Onetouch T10, i am interested in changing my OS to ubuntu. i find it so interesting, i just dont knnow how. hope you can help me.

my tab specs as folows:

Operating System: Android 4.0.3 Ice Cream Sandwich
Application Processor: Rockchip RK2918
CPU: 1GHz Cortex A8
System Memory: 1 GB DDR3
Storage Capacity: 4 GB NAND Flash
Wi-Fi: 802.11 b/g/n
Audio & Video Play: Built-in audio chip, 1080P HD playback
External Interface: Micro USB, Micro SD
Battery: 3000 mAh, 3.7V Lithium
Camera: Front camera 0.3Mpixel

Answer (score 0):

Web search found this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2159354

### Ubuntu Touch on Alcatel

> > Can I get ubuntu touch on Alcatel one touch idol 6030x? And if I can
> >     how to do it am new at this stuff so I will appreciate it
> >
> > See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch#Release
> >
> > that's a lot of work

[end of discussion]

I have seen several apps on google's Play store (and also the "Free and Open Source Software" https://www.f-droid.org ) that are supposed to let you install **Debian** onto android devices. FYI Ubuntu is based on Debian.